# How to enable autocomplete location in string as parameter of function in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

`Project/public/dashboard/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` is full directory but since `public` will only be available to users I set `public` directory as "Resource Root" and starts autocompleting in "src" files but obviously not in string for function parameter. I'm using framework which will generate link dynamically so obviously I can't use static links, that's why I'm using `base_url` function.

Is there anyway I can define anywhere in PhpStorm to take location starting from public folder as root in string as parameter in `base_url()` function?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url('dashboard/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>
```

[image: Autocomplete Error]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't, there's no way to inject a path reference into a string. Please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20028

Comment: @EugeneMorozov You can create custom Language Injection rule and inject HTML into a specific statement (e.g. into all `echo` statements -- see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001929319-Autoinject-HTML-into-echo). **1)** Can this be done for a specific function name? **2)** If it's possible, what's the difference between HTML and FileReference injections?

Comment: @LazyOne **1)** Yes, you can, the latter pattern lets you do that **2)** FileReference injections are just not available from the UI, it's a missing feature

Comment: @EugeneMorozov FileReference does not seem to even work via `@lang` injection .. but it says `Fixed` in WebStorm 2019.2 (for JS or TS). When `FileRerence` will be available in PhpStorm?

Comment: @EugeneMorozov What would be the language Injection rule if I want to inject another language (lets say HTML or CSS) into a **specific** parameter of a **specific** function?

Comment: I don't know when FileReference injections for PHP are gonna be implemented. The last summer we discussed that it's a very important feature, but it hasn't gone anywhere since then. You can inject into a specific parameter, only into the first one. You can do that since 2019.2, the pattern would be `+ phpFirstArgument(phpWithName(string().oneOf("myMethod", "myFunction")))`: http://prntscr.com/o9jar9

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Thanks, appreciate the fast answers.